# Craft CMS and Craft console

Tags: craft4, upgrades

I have installed Craft CMS on a server, and I'm admin. I opted to the Pro version trial for 14 days.
I am now trying to pay for the Pro version and it is sending me to the craft console, yet I can't login there with my Craft CMS admin credential.
So I created an account with the same email address as my admin account in craft cms.
I can now login to the craft console with these new creds (different from my craft cms one) but I'm reluctant to pay for the upgrade on that console not knowing how it is linked to my craft cms account... any clarity would be welcome. thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Craft CMS account and the Craft Console account are completely separate. They don't need to share the same e-mail address. Your CMS account is only stored in your local Craft installation, it's not connected to the Craft Console account in any way.

When you activate the Craft Pro trial, you get a trial license key. When you buy the Craft license through the Console, this trial key will become a valid Craft license. You may need to clear caches and/or log out and log back in, then the warning in the Control Panel about the trial license should go away.

Every license key is connected to one domain, you can change the connected domain in the Craft Console.

In some situations (for example, if the license key is already used on another site), you might get a new license key. In this case, place the `license.key` in `config/license.key` for Craft to pick it up (or add it in your `.env` file if you're configuring the license key through the environment).

Comment: Thank you upgrade successful :-)